# I can't install or remove any apps

Tags: system-installation, software-installation, dependencies, software-uninstall

I get a notification for updating libreoffice, but I have deleted libreoffice and install openoffice many times ago,so when i want to install or remove any apps I get this error:

```
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these: The
following packages have unmet dependencies:  libreoffice : Depends:
fonts-sil-gentium-basic but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libreoffice-base but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libreoffice-report-builder-bin but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libreoffice-java-common (>= 1:5.1.6~rc2~) but it is not going to be installed  libreoffice-core : Depends:
libreoffice-common (> 1:5.1.6~rc2) but it is not going to be installed
libreoffice-ogltrans : Depends: libreoffice-common but it is not going
to be installed  libreoffice-style-elementary : Depends:
libreoffice-common (= 1:5.1.6~rc2-0ubuntu1~xenial3) but it is not
going to be installed  libreoffice-style-galaxy : Depends:
libreoffice-common (= 1:5.1.6~rc2-0ubuntu1~xenial3) but it is not
going to be installed  libreoffice-style-tango : Depends:
libreoffice-common (= 1:5.1.6~rc2-0ubuntu1~xenial3) but it is not
going to be installed E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install'
with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I can't install synaptic to solve this error, because I get this again!
Note: I have tried `sudo apt-get -f install` but I get this error again!
How can I solve it!?

Comment: try sudo dpkg --configure -a to try and resolve those broken dependencies.

Comment: how can i resolve these dependencies? //// libreoffice-ogltrans////
 ////libreoffice-style-galaxy////
//// libreoffice-core////
//// libreoffice-calc////
/// libreoffice-style-elementary////
/// python3-uno////
 ////libreoffice-style-tango////
//// libreoffice-gnome/////
 ////libreoffice-pdfimport////
/// libreoffice-gtk////
/// libreoffice-draw///
/// unoconv///
/// libreoffice-avmedia-backend-gstreamer////
 ///libreoffice-writer///
 ////libreoffice-impress///
//// libreoffice-math////
/// libreoffice-base-core////

Comment: no problem, can you mark the answer below?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sudo dpkg --configure -a to try and resolve those broken dependencies.
more information on dpkg can be found in the ubuntu manpages:
[dpkg manpages](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/dpkg.1.html)